# jenkins job DSL access string param inside node stage

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to create Jenkins pipeline using below DSL script,

```groovy
pipelineJob('pipeline') 
{
  logRotator(numToKeep = 100)
    parameters {
        stringParam("ENV", "dev" , "dev")
        }
definition {    
    cps {
      sandbox()
      script("""
        node {
          stage('Pre Build Test') {

              sh '''#!/bin/bash
              echo "Will deploy to ${params.ENV}" '''
          }
        }""".stripIndent())
    }
  }
}
```

want to access `stringParam` inside node stage shell script, above one  `${params.ENV}` is not working, is there any other way by which i can access string param inside stage shell script?

Answer (score 0):

A Simple ${ENV} should do it, instead of ${params.ENV}

Anyway, your code doesn't look like a valid pipeline. You better switch to a declarative Pipeline, such as:

```groovy
pipeline
{
    parameters
    {
        string(name: 'ENV', defaultValue: 'dev', description: 'dev')
    }

    options
    {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '100'))
    }

    agent any
    stages
    {
        stage('Pre Build Test')
        {
            steps
            {
                script
                {
                    sh '''
                        #!/bin/bash
                        echo "Will deploy to ${ENV}" 
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```